# JSON Decoding Error in pods of GetStreamActivityFeed

Tags: ios, swift, getstream-io

The sample app here https://getstream.io/ios-activity-feed/tutorial/  is working good using the sample Client api key, app id, and token.  Really uploads and downloads Posts that are viewable in the dashboard. However, when I change the api key, app id, and token to mine (I submitted the email to an online Nodejs get stream backend to produce the token), though I am able to push a Post and view in the dashboard, the download fails with this error message:

JSON decoding error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format..

I compare the data in the two dashboards online and noted that Post in both are of the same types.

At first, I really thought that the FlatFeedViewController in the sample app was a fast and clean solution.

I used 100% code from this link.

In AppDelegate:

```
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxx",
            appId: "xxxx",
            token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

        Client.shared.getCurrentUser(typeOf: GetStreamActivityFeed.User.self) { result in
            if result.error == nil, let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
                 viewController.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

In the viewcontroller:

```
class ViewController:  FlatFeedViewController<GetStreamActivityFeed.Activity> {
    let textToolBar = TextToolBar.make()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        appDelegate.getStream()

        if let feedId = FeedId(feedSlug: "timeline") {
            let timelineFlatFeed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedId)
            presenter = FlatFeedPresenter<GetStreamActivityFeed.Activity>(flatFeed: timelineFlatFeed, reactionTypes: [.likes, .comments])
        }

        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTextToolBar()
        subscribeForUpdates()
    }

    func setupTextToolBar() {
        textToolBar.addToSuperview(view, placeholderText: "Share something...")
        // Enable URL unfurling.

        textToolBar.linksDetectorEnabled = true
        // Enable image picker.
        textToolBar.enableImagePicking(with: self)
        textToolBar.sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(save(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func save(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        view.endEditing(true)

        if textToolBar.isValidContent, let presenter = presenter {
            textToolBar.addActivity(to: presenter.flatFeed) { result in
                print(result) // It will print the added activity or error.
            }
        }
    }
```

I expected the uploaded Posts to be downloaded in the app. But the decoding error results. The error is thrown in the public final class Activity, specifically in the function:  public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

Please help.

Comment: Can you share the response code from the request that works?

Comment: The Posts just simply get's displayed in the app as they are downloaded. By the way, the code are the same for both the success and failure as I simply changed the  variables api key, app id, and token. The change should not be the reason as I was able to upload successfully.

Comment: There's no response code that I can see in the Activity class inside the pods. Just this: 
```
public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        text = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .text)
        attachment = try container.decodeIfPresent(ActivityAttachment.self, forKey: .attachments)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
```